# How can I modify a blank line with a new line using sed

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I would like to insert the word "NO" in all of the blank lines in this file using the sed command

```
1234
124
12453
12463
13442
3462



421532
124135

12
```

I am trying this command but I am not sure why it does not work:

```
sed '/'[:blank:]'/ c\ NO' inputfile.txt > outputfile.text
```

Would it be easier to not use sed command?

Comment: Do `blank lines` always contain nothing, or is a line that only contains white space also considered a `blank line`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitute lines that begin and end with a newline with NO, using anchors.

```
sed 's/^$/NO/' inputfile.txt > outputfile.text
```

Comment: Works well with _empty_ lines. The sentence "lines that begin and end with a newline" is misleading: in the context of `sed`, by default, a line is what is _between_ newlines and therefore itself doesn't contain them. `^` matches the start of the line (pattern space) at hand, and `$` its end. In other words: `^$` matches a line that is the empty string.

Answer (score 2):

[POSIX `[:blank:]`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap07.html#tag_07_03_01) denotes only spaces and tabs, not empty lines. Also in case of regex, you should use `[[:blank:]]`.

```
sed 's/[[:blank:]]/NO/' inputfile.txt > outputfile.text
```

If you just want to replace empty lines/lines with spaces or tabs with `NO`, then use this

```
sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*$/NO/' inputfile.txt > outputfile.text
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace empty lines with NO using sed:

`sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*$/NO/' inputfile.txt > outputfile.text`

- ^ - beggining of the line
- $ - end of the line
- [:blank:]* - 0 or more blank characters